# toggling globalKeyEvent on\off

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, processing

I have a processing.js code running on an html page. Once the code finishes its run a form is called with a textarea to be filled out in it.
I'm having an issue where the processing code (which is still active since it uses the information filled in the form) denies me from typing in my textarea since globalKeyEvent is set to true which means all key events in the page are sent to the processing code.

On the other hand if I set globalKeyEvent to false the text area will work properly but I will have to click on the processing window when I want it to receive my commands which is very non user friendly.

Is there a way to toggle on/off (true/false) the globalKeyEvent or any other way to inform the processing code that its not its turn to get keyboard commands?

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's very difficult to help... Please show the Code.

And I didn't understood you so well.. Do you want to disable (if you want to type something in the textarea) that the KeyEvents are sent to "processing-code";

If yes, why dont you use http://api.jquery.com/focus/?

By using:

```
$(element).focus(function(){
textareIsUsed = true;
};
$(element).focusout(function(){
textareIsUsed = false;
};
```

and then check in "processing-code" if "textareIsUsed" is false, then get KeyEvents.

```
if(!textareIsUsed){
   //do stuff in here
}
```